# Give access to app's Documents folder to another app in iOS 11

Tags: ios, react-native, ios11

We've developed an app using React Native that downloads and internally views documents, but to view PowerPoint files it saves the file to its documents directory and uses an external app to view the file (opens a system dialogue to choose which app).

It worked fine in iOS 10, but with iOS 11 it suddenly stopped working. I'm getting a "No such file or directory" error. I'm guessing it's because of security permissions. I tried adding the UISupportsDocumentBrowser key, UIFileSharingEnabled and LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace keys in the app's Info.plist and setting them to true as [recommended by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller) to give access to my app's documents directory, but that didn't fix the issue. I think those keys might be just for the user accessing the app's documents, not another app.

We're using [react-native-document-controller](https://github.com/deldreth/react-native-document-controller) to pass the file, but when it passes the document path to another app to open, we get a `The file couldn’t be opened because there is no such file` error from the controller code. The file is on the device, because if the app either renders the file internally or in the dialog I choose to save it to my files folder instead of viewing it, that works fine. None of the apps that we try to open the file with can do so, however.

Is there anything else I need to do to enable an external app to access my app's documents directory and open the file? Should I not be saving the file to my app's documents directory?

The longer error message is as follows (edited to remove app ID in path and the file's actual name):

> Couldn't get file size for
>   file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/filename.pptx
>   -- file:///: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “filename.pptx” couldn’t be opened because there is no such
>   file."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/filename.pptx
>   -- file:///, NSFilePath=/file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/filename.pptx,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1c08429d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2
>   "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 4):

`UISupportsDocumentBrowser` -> your app's documents can be shown in the Files app / doc browser of other apps.

`LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` -> you know how to open documents in place, using file coordination and security-scoped URLs, without copying them to your container first.

`UIFileSharingEnabled` -> your documents show up in iTunes.

The combination of `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` is used as a heuristic to determine that the Documents folder in the container is sufficiently "clean" to make it showable in the Files app, or in UIDocumentBrowserVC in other apps, for older apps which do not specify `UISupportsDocumentBrowser`

None of these change how your sandbox works.

To open a document in a different app, you have to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`. This will let the user choose which app to use. Which API were you using to open the file previously?

Comment: I'm currently using react-native-document-controller to pass the file, which uses UIDocumentInteractionController. The problem is that when that code goes execute, it does not find the file to pass to another app.

Comment: How do you initialize the DIC? And is your document is stored in the Documents folder inside your container? You’re using a button which copies the file to the other app’s inbox, right? Or is it somehow trying to open-in-place? At which stage does it fail? Any error message?

Comment: We access the DIC through the react-native-document-controller component on top of it. Our class that shows the documents has a reference to it, and passes it the path to the document to open, which is stored in our app's document folder. At that point the document controller can't file the file and errors out. I'll add more info about the error message in the original question.